# Eloquent Relationship - Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys, eloquent, lumen

I have 2 tables, a) Photo b) PhotoLike. I am trying to make a relationship between these models so I can use `->with('')`.

I set up several properly however I don't know why this one is not working.

```
class PhotoLike extends Model {
    public function photo()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Photo');
    }
}
```

---

```
class Photo extends Model {
    public function likes()
    {
      return $this->hasMany('App\PhotoLike');
    }
}
```

---

The database structure looks like:

```
photo_likes table =>  id | photo_id | owner_id
    photos table  =>  id | user_id | ...
```

So `photo_like -> photo_id` `<=>` `photos -> id`

---

This is what I am trying to call:

```
$photos = Photo::with('likes')->where('user_id', $user)->get();
```

As a result I am getting everything except likes. I am receiving: `"likes": []`

Comment: And are you 100% sure you have some photoLikes actually linked in your database to the photos of the $user?

Comment: Ah. Crap! The row I was trying to fetch didn't have any dummy data on the likes side. Thanks